# Can I have Text or Date/Time as input in SAP BPC Input Schedule

Tags: excel, sap-erp, sap-bw

I have a SAP BPC application where I have an Input Schedule. Is it possible to make some of the inputs to accept text or date/time?

For example I have a member called "Details" where the user can enter details about an operation. is it possible to have this field to accept text inputs?

The Input Schedule is build with EVDRE

I use SAP BPC MS 7.5 with excel 2010

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Also consider for next time sending a timestamp (could be epoch format) which is all numbers and could be saved as any other SIGNEDDATA

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a in an input&schedule Excel sheet you can send data to DB.

Just use the following functions for **comments (= text)**:

- EVCGT to get comment from table to Excel
- EVCOM to get comment from table to Excel and from Excel to table

These functions for **numbers (or date/time):**

- EVDRE
- EVGET
- EVSND

Please consider that Excel does not have date/time format, these type of data are simply an [integer or a float number](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time).